# Mapping: Displaced longitude data on basemap

Tags: python, mapping, matplotlib-basemap

I have this basic python code to plot my global data, however when I plot it the longitude (x value) seems to be displaced - moved towards the east.. please check below the code and result

My code is:

```
file = 'frac_0.50.nc'
fileobj_giems = netCDF4.Dataset(file)

cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([[0.0,0.9,1.0],[0.0,0.9,0.0],[1.0,0.9,0.0],[1.0,0.5,0.0],[1.0,0,0]])

frac = fileobj_giems.variables['fwetl'][8,:,:]
pr = frac[:]*100000
lon=fileobj_giems.variables['longitude'][:]
lat=fileobj_giems.variables['latitude'][:]
[lonall, latall] = meshgrid(lon, lat)
fig = plt.figure()
m = Basemap(llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90, llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawparallels(arange(-90.,90.,10.), labels = [1,0,0,0], fontsize = 10)
m.drawmeridians(arange(-180., 180., 10.), labels = [0,0,0,1], fontsize = 10)
levels=arange(2, 11.6, 0.8)
mymapf = plt.contourf(lonall, latall, pr, levels, cmap=cmap)
m.imshow(ma.masked_less_equal((pr),-999999999.),cmap=cmap)

pyplot.show()
```

The result that renders is the following:

[As you see the 'y' seems to be fine but the 'x - lon' data is moved towards the east](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cjEl.png)

Additional info, shape of fileobj_giems.variables['fwetl'] is (180, 360, 720) - (time, lat,lon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a sign error, since the points look to be displaced by 180 degrees; you should check that the sign of your input data is correct (points in North America should have negative values for longitude.)